# item from list of nodes depend on current index of host from hostgroup

Tags: ansible

I am having below setup,

```
groups_var/all.yml
---
cassandra_restore:
  nodes:
   - 192.168.0.1
   - 192.168.0.2
   - 192.168.0.3


inventory contains,

[just_created]
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6


main.yml

---
# playbook 


- name: setup
  hosts: just_created
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
     current_index: "{{ ansible_play_batch.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
       msg: "current host index: {{ ansible_play_batch.index(inventory_hostname) }} : {{ current_index }}"
    - debug:
       msg: "first target host: {{ cassandra_restore.nodes.0 }}"
    - name: get mapped value
      debug:
       msg: "current target host: {{ cassandra_restore.nodes.current_index }} "
```

I want to access item from list of nodes depend on current index of host from hostgroup just_created.
So when the host is 192.168.0.4 it should print 192.168.0.1 and when host is 192.168.0.5 it should print 192.168.0.2 and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
---
# playbook for creating cassandra setup


- name: setup cassnadra
  hosts: just_created
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
     current_index: "{{ ansible_play_batch.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
  tasks:
    - name: get mapped value
      debug:
        msg: "current_index current target host: {{ item.index }} : {{ item.host }} : {{ current_index }}  "
      when: current_index == item.index
      with_items:
        - "{{ cassandra_restore }}"
```

I got this working with following variables,

```
cassandra_restore:
  - { index: "0", host: 192.168.0.1 }
  - { index: "1", host: 192.168.0.2 }
  - { index: "2", host: 192.168.0.3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the map form to access with a dynamic index or key:

```
- name: get mapped value
  debug:
    msg: "current target host: {{ cassandra_restore.nodes[current_index] }} "
```

But I'm not sure the order of the hosts is deterministic.

Comment: Thx for the reply but this gives me following error,

"the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined."